# Pointers passed by reference in Delphi (import functions from DLL)

Tags: c, delphi, pointers, dll, delphi-xe7

I want to use a function declared in a DLL which takes pointers as in/out parameters to fill up a record with non-pointer parameters.

Function from DLL:

```
function WFS_GetMlaData(   handle: WFS_HDL;
                           mla_idx: Integer;
                           mla_name:  TCharWFSBufferArray;
                       var cam_pitch_um: PDouble;
                       var lenslet_pitch_um: PDouble;
                       var center_spot_offset_x: PDouble;
                       var center_spot_offset_y: PDouble;
                       var lenslet_f_um: PDouble;
                       var grd_corr_0: PDouble;
                       var grd_corr_45: PDouble): Integer stdcall;
```

Record:

```
MlaInfo = record
    i : Integer;
    idx : Integer;
    name : TCharWFSBufferArray;
    camPitchUm : double;
    lensletPitchUm : double;
    spotOffsetx : double;
    spotOffsety : double;
    lensletFocalLengthUm : double;
    grdCorr0 : double;
    grdCorr45 : double;
end;
```

Function call:

```
if err = WFS_GetMlaData(handle,
                        MlaList[i].idx,
                        MlaList[i].name,
                        PDouble(MlaList[i].camPitchUm),
                        PDouble(MlaList[i].lensletPitchUm),
                        PDouble(MlaList[i].spotOffsetx),
                        PDouble(MlaList[i].spotOffsety),
                        PDouble(MlaList[i].lensletFocalLengthUm),
                        PDouble(MlaList[i].grdCorr0),
                        PDouble(MlaList[i].grdCorr45) ) then MyWFS_HandleErrors(handle, err);
```

With a similar function which passes pointers to integer it works, in the case above I have *Invalid Typecast* error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You tagged this c++, but there's nothing about C++ here. Perhaps you meant to include the C++ (probably really C) declaration of this DLL function. Please [edit] your question to include that.

Comment: Why did you change which answer you accepted? Your current selection suggests a solution you can't implement (because you're not allowed to change the DLL function) and then suggests a dubious type-cast that probably only compiles when you have the "typed @ operator" option disabled (which is a bad idea). Your previous selected offered two changes you could make that would work and give you cleaner code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the [Parameters (Delphi) - Value and Variable Parameters](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Value_and_Variable_Parameters) documentation. My bold emphasizes it:

> **If a routine's declaration specifies a var parameter, you must pass an assignable expression - that is, a variable, typed constant** (in the {$J+} state), *dereferenced pointer*, field, or indexed variable to the routine when you call it.

---

Regarding your case, my advice is to declare a new type:

```
PMlaInfo = ^TMlaInfo;
```

And change the signature of the function:

```
function WFS_GetMlaData(AHandle: WFS_HDL; const AMlaInfo: PMlaInfo): Integer stdcall;
```

---

But there's a sort of "*hack*" (dereferenced pointer):

```
PDouble((@MlaList[i].camPitchUm)^)
```

Comment: `PDouble((@MlaList[i].camPitchUm)^)` works, it's better for me because I can't change function signature.

Comment: yes, also declaring all those variables would be boring :-\

Answer (score 4):

Your DLL function is declared incorrectly. The original C code has all those parameters as pointers to double — `double*`. The sure-fire, can't-go-wrong solution is for you to change the function declaration to match the C code. Remove the `var` modifiers from all the function parameters.

The alternative solution is again for you to change the function declaration, but this time to make it look a little more like idiomatic Delphi. Keep the `var` modifiers, but change the parameters' type to `Double` instead of `PDouble`.

If you make the first change, then you would call the function by passing pointers to the record members: `@MlaList[i].camPitchUm` with no type casting. If you make the second change instead, then you would call the function by passing the record members directly, again with no type casting: `MlaList[i].camPitchUm`.

Comment: Correct me If I'm wrong, using `var` and pointer gives me pointer to pointer?